# How to pass no value to Date object using TypeScript null check

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am looking way to do something like

```
value ? new Date(value) : new Date()
```

using TypeScript null check

```
new Date(value ?? xxx)
```

It is even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now):

```
new Date(value ?? Date.now())
```

Note that `value` should be a number in this case. If it is a string, you'll need to use:

```
new Date(value ?? new Date(Date.now()).toISOString())`
```

at which point you're better off with the original code, in my opinion. That said, be aware of the problems with depending on date parsing using the `Date` constructor, outlined in [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)